# document.execCommand() is not working in IE

Tags: html, css

document.execCommand('bold',null,false);

This is not working when i tried in IE but works fine in mozilla.
For Demo open http://jsfiddle.net/hqvDT/1/ this link in mozilla (bold functionality works) but in IE (bold functionality doen't work)... i guess this document.execCommand() is the issue. Please correct me if i am wrong in guess.

Answer (score 0):

Available only in the Win32 platforms for IE Try this.

http://goo.gl/FJXGM

Comment: ya but im using 32-bit OS (x86) and i have checked in IE8, IE7 but still issue remains..